# Dynamodb - Eclipse Error

Tags: titan, dynamo-local

Firstly i am using

Titan Graph 1.0.0

Backend Storage = DynamoDB_Local

I am deleting graph created and stored in local P.C.

I have code as below

{

```
    BaseConfiguration conf = new BaseConfiguration();

    conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager");
    conf.setProperty("storage.dynamodb.client.endpoint", "http://localhost:4567");
    conf.setProperty("storage.dynamodb.enable-parallel-scan", "true");
    conf.setProperty("ids.flush", "false");conf.setProperty("faunus.output.titan.storage.index.search.backend", "elasticsearch");
    conf.setProperty("faunus.graph.output.titan.storage.index.search.hostname", "/tmp/searchindex");
    conf.setProperty("faunus.graph.output.titan.storage.index.search.elasticsearch.client-only", "false");
    conf.setProperty("faunus.graph.output.titan.storage.index.search.elasticsearch.local-mode", "true");



    TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(conf);
    graph.close();
    TitanCleanup.clear(graph);

    System.out.println("graph delete");
    System.exit(0);
}}
```

And when i run this code gives me an error like this

`Exception in thread "main" com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not initialize backend
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.initialize(Backend.java:301)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1806)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.<init>(StandardTitanGraph.java:123)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:74)
    at deleteGraph.main(deleteGraph.java:56)
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: CreateTable_titan_graphindex Cannot increase provisioned throughput to more than 80,000 units per account (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 34d7515c-d628-4224-bca3-b75acb936c71)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBDelegate.processDynamoDBAPIException(DynamoDBDelegate.java:215)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBDelegate.createTable(DynamoDBDelegate.java:702)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBDelegate.createTableAndWaitForActive(DynamoDBDelegate.java:838)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.AbstractDynamoDBStore.ensureStore(AbstractDynamoDBStore.java:92)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.MetricStore.ensureStore(MetricStore.java:47)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.TableNameDynamoDBStoreFactory.create(TableNameDynamoDBStoreFactory.java:52)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager.openDatabase(DynamoDBStoreManager.java:202)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager.openDatabase(DynamoDBStoreManager.java:57)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.initialize(Backend.java:235)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: Cannot increase provisioned throughput to more than 80,000 units per account (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 34d7515c-d628-4224-bca3-b75acb936c71)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1579)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1249)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1835)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1811)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.createTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:640)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBDelegate.createTable(DynamoDBDelegate.java:700)
    ... 12 more`

I don't know how to solve this error also no reference has been given for this exception 
Can anyone help it...!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be running the stack in us-east-1, as the maximum provisioned throughput is 80k there. You omitted the edgestore/graphindex provisioning configuration, but I suspect you tried to provision more than 80000 units of provisioned throughput. To get more throughput, you need to [file a request through AWS support to have the per table and per region throughput limits raised](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-capacity-units-provisioned-throughput).